# Do you need to remove an alarm before setting new one

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have an Android `alarmManager` being set and a `broadcastReceiver` to pick it up, whenever the app triggers `onResume`, I am forcing a new alarm to be set.

So I'm wondering for best practices and considering good resource management, should I be removing the first alarm (if it hasn't triggered) before I reset a new alarm ?

Potentially if an alarm doesn't trigger, each time the user re-opens the app, is it creating more resource usage even if the alarm is for the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you should cancel it when it is appropriate.

I suspect you will have a lot of wasted cycles otherwise. For Example,
App opens at Time T.
Schedule an alarm for T'.
Next the user opens the app again at some time, X seconds prior to T'.
You will then schedule an alarm presumable at another time T''.
However you will get an alarm firing in X secs anyways. If you ignore it, you are simply wasting battery if the phone had to wake in order to deliver the alarm.

Comment: not too sure i follow you - I should have specified also, that onResume when new alarm is set - it will always be the same as the last one (again, if that last one hasn't triggered)

Answer (score 0):

If you create the same PendingIntent for your alarm, then the previous one will automatically be canceled when you set it again.

See [AlarmManager.set()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#set%28int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29), [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html).